# Time is displayed wrong is Google Search for Politico Stories

Tags: html, timestamp, google-search, google-search-api, google-crawlers

At Politico, our stories do not seem to have a date or time available for Google search to crawl. This is causing an issue where stories are showing as being published before they were actually published in Google's search results.
For example, http://www.politico.com/story/2017/04/21/sahar-nowrouzzadeh-reassigned-state-department-237466 was actually published on `04/21/17 03:18 PM EDT`, but showing on google search it was publishes 12 hours ago when searching on the same date, 10 minutes later.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PW4BO.png]

However Google news displays the time fine.

We've added some micro data following `schema.org` definition but it doesn't seem to help:

```
<p class="timestamp"><time itemprop="datePublished" datetime='2017-04-21T03:18-0400'>04/21/17 03:18 PM EDT</time></p>
```

Do you have any idea why Google Search doesn't pick up the correct time?

Comment: This is probably better asked on Pro Webmasters. See https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/90817/3922